# trailing slah with different directory in rewrite chain

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i got a problem which is probably caused cause of my strange directory structure. i got a folder where my page is in and inside this folder i got a folder named `/admin/` and `/frontend/`.

i got the following inside `/.htaccess`

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} mypage\.local$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/frontend
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /frontend/$1 [L]
```

then inside my `/frontend/` i got an index.php and there i set up what content will be displayed. inside `/admin/` i disable the mod rewrite and use normal url with .php requests.

i got the following inside my `/frontend/.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z_\-0-9]+)/$ /frontend/index.php?main=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z_\-0-9]+)/([A-Za-z_\-0-9\.]+)/$ /frontend/index.php?main=$1&sub=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z_\-0-9\.\&]+\.html)$ /frontend/index.php?main=html&sub=$1 [L,QSA]
```

now urls like /test/ and /test/test/ will be redirected to my `/frontend/index.php` and i can perform actions.

is there a possibility that i can catch all other urls and redirect to my index.php?

if tried this, but then i get a 505

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /frontend/index.php?main=$1 [L,QSA]
```

thanks for any help.

Comment: An HTTP 505 error means that your server doesn't support the HTTP version it was requested with. I would suspect an issue somewhere else other than rewrite rules. [More info on HTTP status codes](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have these rules in `/frontend/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /frontend/

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?main=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w.-]+)/?$ index.php?main=$1&sub=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([\w.&-]+\.html)$ index.php?main=html&sub=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?main=$1 [L,QSA]
```